# wp_get_attachment_image_src and server path

Tags: images, attachments

[`wp_get_attachment_image_src`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) will give me URL and dimensions for an image.

But is there any way to get the server path for a scaled image (like `/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/cat-2-300x225.jpeg`)? I know about [`get_attached_file`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_file) but this returns only the original image.

I'd like to avoid hacky solutions (string-replacing domains and such) or using `WP_Image_Editor` directly. Also it should be multisite-proof. Is there something official I've just missed?

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144409/how-to-get-list-of-paths-not-urls-for-an-image?rq=1) seems to be a duplicate, but has the flaws you mentioned. Just posting for completeness sake. :)

Comment: have you looked into http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata

Comment: Yep. But that just returns something like `2015/03/cat-2.jpeg`. Though it *does* also return all file names for generated thumbnails, but only the filenames – and this again leads to cumbersome manipulation of paths.

Comment: I know, but I am afraid this is the closest you get. May I also ask what you need this for?

Comment: I'm on a plugin to integrate the post image as an [RSS enclosure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_enclosure) into the WordPress generated feeds and therefore need to know the file size (and mime type).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

WordPress doesn't store path of generated sizes anywhere, you need to *build* it.

As suggested by [@kraftner](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/47733/kraftner) in comments, [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_metadata/) can be used to obtain some of the pieces you need to build the path. An alternative is [`image_get_intermediate_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_get_intermediate_size/).

The *missing piece* is the absolute path of upload folder. *In theory*, that can be retrieved via  [`wp_upload_dir()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_upload_dir/) but there's a problem: that function returns the upload folder in the moment it is called, but there's always the possibility that when the file was uploaded the upload path was different.

So the **only** possibility is to make the assumption that scaled image is in the same folder of original image.

This assumption may appear hackish, and probably is, but it is used in WordPress core itself by functions like [image_downsize()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/image_downsize/) that does exactly *string-replacing* (see line [#184 of `media.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1/src/wp-includes/media.php#L184)), so if you're looking for the *official way*.. that's the one.

Putting things togheter:

```
function scaled_image_path($attachment_id, $size = 'thumbnail') {
    $file = get_attached_file($attachment_id, true);
    if (empty($size) || $size === 'full') {
        // for the original size get_attached_file is fine
        return realpath($file);
    }
    if (! wp_attachment_is_image($attachment_id) ) {
        return false; // the id is not referring to a media
    }
    $info = image_get_intermediate_size($attachment_id, $size);
    if (!is_array($info) || ! isset($info['file'])) {
        return false; // probably a bad size argument
    }

    return realpath(str_replace(wp_basename($file), $info['file'], $file));
}
```

Function above takes the attachment id and a size and returns the path.

I've applied [`realpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) before to return paths because that function returns false for non-existent files, so the whole function always returns false if something went wrong.

The only alternative to this flow would be saving by yourself the path of scaled image(s) somewhere, probably post meta, and retrieve when needed, but that can only work for files uploaded after your plugin has been activated...

Comment: Been down the road you took, dug through the image-generating code (in the end assuming that the scaled image resides in the same folder as the original) and didn't like it. Well, guess I have to back down then. Thanks for your elaborate answer, Sir!

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! A quick post script, to include support for returning the path of SVG files, since there are no relevant sizes to consider, you can add something like `|| strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == "svg"` to the first `if` statement.