# Loading custom post thumbnail into stream

Tags: custom-post-types, post-thumbnails

I would like to get a hold of the feature image to perform image manipulation on it.

First I want to load it, then manipulate it and turn the final image into base64 for displaying it in the HTML.

Any idea how can I get a hold of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to grab the featured image by post's ID, then manipulate it and return it as whatever format you wish.

```
function covert_thumbnail_to_base64($post->ID){
    // Get the thumbnail's URL
    $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID,'thumbnail' );

    // Now, process it the way you want

    // Return the processed image
    return $data;
}
```

Now you can convert the post's thumbnail to base64 by calling `covert_thumbnail_to_base64();`. if you use this inside a loop, you don't have to pass the post's ID to the function. Otherwise, you should feed the function with a post ID.

If you need the absolute path to the image, you can use `get_attached_file()` in conjunction with `get_post_thumbnail_id()`:

```
$file_path = get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
```

Comment: How can I get the thumbnail in a specific size?

Comment: @Yaron Hi. You can change the `thumbnail` in the answer to any size you want.

Comment: But this is a url, not a gd image

Comment: @Yaron If you want to get the absolute path to the other sizes, you have to build it. Check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/182477/94498) question (also the one in the first comment).

Comment: Oh, It was my bad! I eventually used the returning url from get_the_post_thumbnail_url with imagecreatefromjpeg and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much!